# Enable communication between two VMs that are in same subnet but different resource group

Tags: azure

I am new to Azure and have two VMs that are on same subnet but different resource group, the two VMs can't ping each other. I cannot add network peering as they both are in 172.30.x.x network. How can I connect to the VM in resource group A from a VM in resource group B.

Basically a VM in Resource Group B is a samba server and I would access the samba share from a VM that is in Resource Group A. The two VMs can't even ping each other.

Answer (score 3):

Resource groups having nothing to do with networking, they are just a container for organising resources. If the two VM's are connected to the same subnet then they are already configured to be able to talk to each other.

I would guess that the reason why they can't talk currently is that you've got a network level NSG configured on one or both of the VM's blocking the inbound port your interested in. Look at the VM network card settings to see what NSG is applied and open the required ports.

Comment: They might also possibly have local firewall settings preventing the communication.

Comment: The OP is saying they can’t add network peering.  I’m guessing they’re two different VNet’s using the same IP address space (hence not being able to peer).